# Help Needed...Could not access my Stackoverflow Account..!

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, linked-accounts

Respected Admins,

I am unable to access my old account on stackoverflow. When I login to stackoverflow today morning, I got a new account.
I am able to access my meta.stackoverflow account using my google account correctly but can't access the stackoverflow account.

Account Details (Stackoverflow):

Old account : https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155805/haresh-chaudhary
New account : https://stackoverflow.com/users/3306861/user3306861

(Meta Stackoverflow)

Link : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/191458/haresh

I just need my old account back..Please help me.

Comment: If you now go to SO, do you still not have access to your "old" account? It seems linked with this account just fine...

Comment: @Bart When I go to stackoverflow, all I get is a new account which I have mentioned as the New Account link.

Comment: I think my account got unlinked from my email address. So that what I see is a new account.

Comment: Both accounts seem to be using the same credentials, near as I can tell, so the system should have merged them when you tried to log in. Beyond completely logging out of the new account and trying to log back in, use the "contact us" link at the bottom of this page to write the community team. Even moderators can't do anything about whatever is going on here. An SE employee will need to look into this.

Comment: Yes I am trying it as you have suggested @BradLarson and would let you know.

Comment: @BradLarson What I did was I used the recovery account option which asked me to enter my email address. And then I received an email to reset my password. After having reset the password it asked me that whether I want to access the Old account or the newer One and the I selected the Old one and the things are back. I thank you for you kind support.Thanks.

Comment: I Thank You @Bart , BradLarson and Tim Post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you used something in the new account that was present in the old account (email, alternate login, etc) which triggered an automatic merge. As far as I can see, you're now back in your account.

If something like this happens again, [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) us instead, as we might need to get some information from you to sort it out that isn't suitable to be given in public.

Comment: What I did was I used the recovery account option which asked me to enter my email address. And then I received an email to reset my password. After having reset the password it asked me that whether I want to access the Old account or the newer One and the I selected the Old one and the things are back. I thank you for you kind support.
Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked out :)